# Measuring clearance height for dishwasher

Tags: kitchens, installation, dishwasher, kitchen-counters

I am purchasing an 18" dishwasher but not installing it. I have to make sure it is the right size so that there are no issues when the installer comes. I have no idea how to install appliances. My existing cabinets have a base a few inches high under them. Where should I measure the clearance height from in order to get an appropriately sized dishwasher? The dishwasher will be replacing the cabinet and drawer here:

[image]

Should I go all the way to the floor, or to the top of the base? Also, should I go all the way up to the underside of the white counter top, or just up to the bottom of the horizontal wood panel right underneath it?

I don't have a picture of the inside, and not sure if this matters, but the inner floor of the cabinet is at the top of the base (i.e. it's more of a "platform" that the cabinet sits on, sorry I don't know the right terminology).

Also (again, not sure if this matters), much to my pleasant surprise I am getting new counter tops at the same time, if that affects the available options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clearance is the space you have to insert the dishwasher...so that would be from your floor, to the underside of the counter's front lip. Nothing bigger can fit through that space.

New counter tops can help if you have to make the clearance taller than what's currently there, but that will introduce other issues (like having to raise the rest of the cabinets to match).

Finally, do the installers know they are pulling out existing cabinets? Typically an installer just inserts it into an existing opening. You may have to bring in a carpenter or cabinetmaker as well.